# Shuffle a python list without using the built-in function

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm working on writing two different shuffle functions.

The first shuffle function must take a list and return a new list with the elements shuffled into a random order.

This is what I have so far for the first shuffle function-

```
def shuf(List):
    import random
    newList=[]
    for i in List:
        i=random.randrange(len(List))
        newList+=i
    return newList
```

The second shuffle function takes a list as a parameter and shuffles the list in place.

I know how to do it with the built-in function but I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: Would you care to share what you do know, what exactly isn't allowed, and how far you've got in your work to write these two different shuffle functions?

Comment: Do you already know the algorithms you have to implement? What issues are you facing?

Comment: Note that the implementation of Python's `random.shuffle()` is written in Python, so you could just read [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l276).

Comment: This is what I have so far for the first shuffle function-               def shuf(List):
    import random
    newList=[]
    for i in List:
        i=random.randrange(len(List))
        newList+=i
    return newList

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Shuffle from scratch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493008/python-shuffle-from-scratch)

Comment: @gorkypl: This one is older, so I'd vote to close the other.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that this implementation for shuffling suits your needs. Make sure that you note the difference between the two functions before using them.

```
import copy
import random


def main():
    my_list = list(range(10))
    print(my_list)
    print(shuffle(my_list))
    print(my_list)
    shuffle_in_place(my_list)
    print(my_list)


def shuffle(container):
    new_container = copy.copy(container)
    shuffle_in_place(new_container)
    return new_container


def shuffle_in_place(container):
    for index in range(len(container) - 1, 0, -1):
        other = random.randint(0, index)
        if other == index:
            continue
        container[index], container[other] = container[other], container[index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is a poor shuffle since it's biased. For example, if you shuffle [0, 1, 2] it can only produce [1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0] and [0, 2, 1].

Comment: Because the algorithm is biased, arrays must have more than two elements. It is not designed to be perfect, but at least it forces all values to move at least once.

Comment: @PaulHankin The `shuffle_in_place` function has finally been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by python source code implementation of [shuffle](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py) in the random module

```py
  import random

  def shuffle(A):
      last_index = len(A) - 1

      while last_index > 0:
          rand_index = random.randint(0, last_index)
          A[last_index], A[rand_index] = A[rand_index], A[last_index]
          last_index -= 1

      return A
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this code:

```
import random

#define the lists
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list2 = []
run = True

#main code
while run:
    var1 = random.choice(list1)
    var2 = list1.pop(var1)
    list2.append(var2)
    if len(list1) == 0:
        run = False
print (list2)
#output = [randomised list]
```

Answer (score -2):

Plan: Go through the list from the beginning starting with element 0; find a new random position for it, say 6, put 0’s value in 6 and 6’s value in 0. Move on to element 1 and repeat this process, and so on through the rest of the list

```
import random
iteration = random.randint(2, 100)
temp_var = 0
while iteration > 0:
    # We will be swapping the value of i for j.
    # And then setting j to what i was using the temp_var place holder.
    for i in range(1, len(my_list)): # have to use range with len()
        for j in range(1, len(my_list) - i):
            # Using temp_var as my place holder so I don't lose values
            temp_var = my_list[i]
            my_list[i] = my_list[j]
            my_list[j] = temp_var

        iteration -= 1
```