# Python Shuffle from scratch

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that will create a new shuffled list (I can't use the built-in shuffle function)

```
def Shuf(aList):

  import random
  newList=[]
  for i in range(len(aList)):
      element=random.sample(aList,1)
      newList+=element
  return newList
```

This is what I have right now and it's working but when I return the shuffled list there are repeated elements of my list. How can I make my function only return the elements in the list one time?

Comment: Sampling runs the risk of selecting the same item multiple times -- as you've discovered. Rather than sampling, you might consider **swapping** as a strategy.

Comment: shuffle without shuffle, that sounds so much like homework...

Comment: @Guillaume +1 suspicious homework. However there are some things we can give you some guidance. First of all, __do not import modules within a function__, if you could avoid. Second, __try explore the key built-in data structures that Python offers__, and you might be surprised on 1. how easy this problem can be solved 2. how many ways this problem can be solved.

Comment: Google "Fisher-Yates"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shuffle a python list without using the built-in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489477/shuffle-a-python-list-without-using-the-built-in-function)

Answer (score 0):

Since you apparently *can* use `random.sample`:

```
import random

def Shuf(aList):
    return random.sample(aList, len(aList))
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like the next (not tested).

```
from random import choice

def get_list( l ):
    len_ = len( l )
    output = []

    for i in range( len_ ):
        index = choice( len( l ) )
        output.append( l[ index ] )
        del l[ index ]

    return output
```