# Program that shuffles

Tags: python, python-2.7

"Create a text document called names.txt that contains a list of 20 names, each on its own line.  Write a program that reads the names from names.txt and then generates a file called shuffle.txt that contains the names listed in random order.  (Do not use the .shuffle() list method)"

That is the question that was asked. My code is below and I'm stumped. Any tips?
BTW: I will do the new file after I know it is printing right.

```
import random

my_file=open('C://names.txt','r')

name=my_file.read()

my_list=name.split(",")

for names in my_list:

           my_list=random.randint(0,20)

           print my_list
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error message?

Comment: It is printing numbers instead of the names in a different order

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493008/python-shuffle-from-scratch

Comment: And i need some sort of checker to  make sure each number is used once

Comment: KkAlmAacet I cant use def or return as I haven't learned it yet

Comment: @kAlmAcetA, and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489477/shuffle-a-python-list-without-using-the-built-in-function

Comment: again I cant use def or return as I haven't learned it yet

Comment: @JimLarson: The `def` is just used there to make the code reusable.  Just take the block of code underneath it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy + paste

```
import random

f=open('/tmp/names.txt', 'r')
array=f.readlines()  # read all lines
f.close()  # release file
array_len = len(array)
for index in range(array_len):
    swap = random.randrange(array_len - 1)
    swap += swap >= index
    array[index], array[swap] = array[swap], array[index]
f=open('/tmp/shuffle.txt', 'w')  # open dst file
f.write("".join(array))  # save shuffled names
f.close() # release - close file
```

Comment: swap += swap >= index
    array[index], array[swap] = array[swap], array[index]

Comment: In addition to lacking any explanation of what's going on here, the code is actually wrong.  It will not produce a uniformly-distributed shuffle.  The correct way to shuffle a list is the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle), which this code does not correctly implement.  In particular, it chooses `swap` from the length of the entire array rather than the as-yet-unshuffled portion of the array.  The `swap +=` line is also entirely nonsensical (you're adding a boolean to an int: technically legal but why would you do that?).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct implementation of `random.shuffle()`:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  # any list
for i in range(len(items)):
    j = random.randrange(i, len(items))
    items[i], items[j] = items[j], items[i]
```

Some style guides will tell you to use `enumerate()` instead of `range(len(...))`, but in this case it doesn't actually make the code any nicer.

The algorithm works by dividing the list into two partitions: an initially empty partition at the left and a second partition on the right.  Every time through the loop, we randomly select an element from the right partition, swap it with the leftmost element of the right partition, and move the boundary over.

Using our list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, here's an example run:

1. The left partition is empty.  Visualize the list as `[] + ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`
2. `random.randrange(0, 4)` returns `0`.
3. Swap `'a'` with element zero, which happens to also be `'a'`.
4. The list is now `['a'] + ['b', 'c', 'd']`.
5. `random.randrange(1, 4)` returns `3`.
6. Swap `'b'` with element 3, which is `'d'`.
7. We now have `['a', 'd'] + ['c', 'b']`.
8. `random.randrange(2, 4)` returns 2.
9. Swap `'c'` with element 2, which happens to be `'c'`.
10. We have `['a', 'd', 'c'] + ['b']`.
11. `random.randrange(3, 4)` can only return 3.
12. Swap `'b'` with itself.
13. Our final result is `['a', 'd', 'c', 'b']`.